# Basic Grunt.js usage: How to create the correct directory structure

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am running grunt for a font-end development environment.

I have the following directory structure:

```
Project
  -  Dev { My test dir for the build }
       - www
       - img
           - dir 1
           - dir 2

  -  Dist { The distribution dir, post grunt compile }
```

I have the following code to copy the image files across in my grunt.js file:

```
img: {
             expand: false,
             src: ["dev/img/*"],
             dest: 'dist/img/',
                },
```

This copies files fine, but I end up with dist/dev/img/(dir1 etc) when I actually want dist/img/(dir 1 etc). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, I found the answer here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy.

You need to use the CWD to set the base dir:

```
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'dev/',
            src: ['img/*'],
            dest: 'dist/img/',
            flatten: true,
            filter: 'isFile',
```

Comment: If you have files under sub-directories in the img directory, you need to use `['img/**/*']` otherwise you are only copying files that are directly in **img/** but not in sub-directories.